# Probability of taking at least one ball of specific color, no reposition, order doesn't matter

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A bag contains 9 balls. 4 are red, 3 are white and 2 are yellow. Three
>   balls are extracted in a succession, without reposition.
>
> What is the probability of extracting at least 1 yellow ball?

I did:

- probability of 1 yellow ball:

(A is yellow and B is other color)

$$p(ABB) = \frac{2}{9}$$
$$p(BAB) = \frac{2}{8}$$
$$p(BBA) = \frac{2}{7}$$

- total = $\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{7}=\frac{191}{252}$

$$\\$$

- probability of getting 2 yellow balls:
  $$p(AAB)=\frac{2}{9}*\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{36}$$
  $$p(ABA)=\frac{2}{9}*\frac{1}{7} = \frac{2}{63}$$
  $$p(BAA)=\frac{2}{8}*\frac{1}{7} = \frac{1}{28}$$
- total = $\frac{1}{36}+\frac{2}{63}+\frac{1}{28}=\frac{2}{21}$

So the probability of getting at least 1 yellow ball is $$\frac{2}{21}+\frac{191}{252} = \frac{215}{252} = .85%$$

But my book says the solution is about 58.3%.
What did I do wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Why would you say that $P(ABB)=\frac 29$?

Comment: The value for $P(ABB)$ is not right. The probability that the first ball is yellow is $\frac29$. OK. But then you have to draw two non-yellow balls. The probability for that is $\frac78\cdot \frac67$. Therefore $P(ABB)=\frac29\cdot \frac78\cdot \frac67$. Similarly for the other cases. It is comprehensible ? Hint: You will see that $P(ABB)=P(BAB)=P(BBA)$

Comment: Conceptually, I'd say you were better off working with the complimentary event...that is, compute the probability of getting no yellow balls.

Comment: you need to think about the chance of getting a yellow ball based on what has already happened, how many balls are left, and multiply each draw together - for example $P(BBA) = (7/9)(6/8)(2/7) = 1/6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways of extracting 3 balls that are *not* yellow, and $\binom{9}{3}$ possibile extractions. So the probability of extracting 3 non-yellow balls is

$$
p=\frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{9}{3}}.
$$

Then the probability of extracting at least one yellow ball is

$$
\overline{p}=1-p=1-\frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{9}{3}}=1-\frac{5}{12}=\frac{7}{12}\approx 58.3\%.
$$

Comment: The other answers are correct and helped me understand this problem, but yours is simpler and faster. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

As a general principle, when you see a question that refers to "at least (a **Certain Number**)", consider instead answering the complementary question "less than (a **Certain Number**)".  The calculation is often easier, and needs only be subtracted from $1$, to yield the solution to the original problem.(As pointed out by @Zar)

In this case the probability of missing the two yellow balls on the first draw from the $9$ in the bag is $\frac79$.

The probability of *then* missing the $2$ yellows in the $8$ remaining on the second draw is $\frac68$

The probability of *then* missing the $2$ yellows in the $7$ remaining on the third draw is $\frac57$

The probability of these three draws missing the yellows is then $$P_{Miss}=\frac{7\times 6 \times 5}{9\times 8 \times 7}=\frac5{12}$$So $$P_{Hit}=\frac7{12}$$